# URI escape / unescape from Javascript to Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, escaping, uri

I have an URL that javascript reads from an user input.
Here is a part of javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("Snd_Cont_AddrLnk_BG").value=encodeURI(document.getElementById("Con_AddresWeb_BG").value.toString());
```

Then I post the value of the string through CGI to a Perl Script (here is a part of perl code):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
##
##

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use URI::Escape;

my $C_AddrLnk_BG=$query->param("Snd_Cont_AddrLnk_BG");

my $lst_upload_dir="../data";
my $lst_file_bg=$lst_upload_dir."/contacts_bg.js";

open(JSBG,">$lst_file_bg") || die "Failed to open $lst_file_bg\n";
printf JSBG "var GMapLink_bg=\"".uri_unescape($C_AddrLnk_BG)."\";\n";
close JSBG;
system("chmod 777 $lst_file_bg");
```

Somewhere in uri_unescape a problem occurs:
The original string from input is:

```
https://www.google.bg/maps/place/42%C2%B044'15.0%22N+23%C2%B019'04.2%22E/@42.7368454,23.317962,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0
```

The string after javascript encodeURI() is:

```
https://www.google.bg/maps/place/42%25C2%25B044'15.0%2522N+23%25C2%25B019'04.2%2522E/@42.7368454,23.317962,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0
```

And the script after perl uri_unescape() that is printed in file is:

```
https://www.google.bg/maps/place/42%C2%B044'15.0%22N+23%C2%B019'04.2          0.000000E+00/@42.7368454,23.317962,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0
```

I can not ascertain whether the problem is in unescaping or printing, but the part

> %2522E

is interpreted as

> ```
>       0.000000E+00
> ```

(with 10 leading spaces).

Can anyone help me with an idea of what I was doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect you are using a `printf` that should be a `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `printf` instead of `print` to output the result of `uri_unescape`. It is interpreting `%22E` as an engineering-format floating point field with a width of 22. Presumable you have nothing else in the `printf` parameter list, so `undef` is being evaluated as zero, resulting in           `0.000000E+00`.

If you had `use warnings` in place as you should, you would see messages like `Missing argument in printf`

Comment: "If you had `use warnings` in place as you should, you would see messages like `Missing argument in printf`" OP is using `-w` but since this is a CGI script, warnings are probably going directly to the webserver's error log. They might want to use `CGI::Carp`'s [`warningsToBrowser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp#MAKING-WARNINGS-APPEAR-AS-HTML-COMMENTS) during development to catch these (as long as they remove the calls in production!)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, hum, if you're at the point that post for help on SO, perhaps you should have checked for error messages?

Comment: @Borodin Yes, you are absolutely right. Using warnings is always a good idea. If I've used, I would get an idea for the essence of the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @byddles: And `use warnings` is preferable to `-w` on the shebang line

Comment: @ikegami I don't disagree with that. I'm just saying that the advice "use warnings" might be more helpful if you also tell the OP where to look for warnings, since they don't seem to know.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous problems with your code.

> ```
> document.getElementById("Snd_Cont_AddrLnk_BG").value =
>     encodeURI(document.getElementById("Con_AddresWeb_BG").value.toString());
> ```

I can't figure out when you think `encodeURI` here. All you should have is the following:

```
document.getElementById("Snd_Cont_AddrLnk_BG").value =
    document.getElementById("Con_AddresWeb_BG").value;
```

> ```
> printf JSBG "var GMapLink_bg=\"".uri_unescape($C_AddrLnk_BG)."\";\n";
> ```

Now the erroneous `encodeURI` is removed, `uri_unescape` needs to be removed too.

Furthermore, adding quotes around text doesn't always make it a valid JavaScript literal. The easiest way to do that is as follows:

```
use JSON qw( );

my $json = JSON->new()->allow_nonref();
$json->encode($C_AddrLnk_BG)
```

That snippet also misuses `printf`. `printf` takes a format parameter, so you want

```
printf FH "%s", ...
```

or simply

```
print FH ...
```

So what you end up with is:

```
use JSON qw( );

my $json = JSON->new()->allow_nonref();
$json->encode($C_AddrLnk_BG)
print JSBG "var GMapLink_bg=" . $json->encode($C_AddrLnk_BG) ."\n";
```

---

Comment: This answer covers three bugs in addition to one Borodin mentioned.